# ClosedXML Template not setting data into excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am trying to put data into cells using `closedxml` and according to their site we have to set parameters like this on the cells `{{TestName}}` but it won't work for me.

This is my code and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
const string outputFile = @"\\Reports\Output\Test.xlsx";
var template = new XLTemplate(@"\\Reports\Test.xlsx");

var test = new models.Test();
test.id = 1;
test.TestName = "ASDF";
test.TestScore = "303";

template.AddVariable(test) //also tried doing it like this.


template.AddVariable("TestScore", "232");
template.AddVariable("TestName", "TESTNAME");
template.SaveAs(outputFile);
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(outputFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
```

And my excel template looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

Just add `template.Generate();` after adding the variables into the template.

Comment: do have a repo example about it ?

Comment: no just add the template.Generate() before saving the file & it should add the variables